# Decode an encoded javascript, edit and then encode again

Tags: javascript, encoding, decoding

I found an encoded javascript inside my template. I decoded it using a online decoder. I edited the then-newly decoded javascript. How can I encode this edited javascript again and use inside my teplate? Here's code:

```
 var _0xb8b1=["\x72\x20\x31\x61\x28\x75\x29\x7B\x76\x2E\x54\x28\x27\x3C\x50\x20\x70\x3D\x22\x31\x31\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x70\x3D\x22\x67\x20\x67\x2D\x31\x66\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x31\x67\x2B\x27\x20\x3C\x2F\x50\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x6A\x3D\x28\x57\x29\x3F\x4D\x2E\x31\x65\x28\x28\x6D\x2E\x37\x2B\x31\x29\x2A\x4D\x2E\x31\x6C\x28\x29\x29\x3A\x30\x3B\x68\x3D\x31\x33\x20\x31\x64\x28\x29\x3B\x33\x20\x65\x3D\x27\x3C\x7A\x20\x31\x68\x3D\x22\x4A\x22\x3E\x27\x3B\x41\x28\x33\x20\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x49\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x75\x2E\x48\x2E\x32\x5B\x69\x5D\x3B\x33\x20\x47\x3B\x33\x20\x6F\x3B\x34\x28\x69\x3D\x3D\x75\x2E\x48\x2E\x32\x2E\x37\x29\x71\x3B\x41\x28\x33\x20\x6B\x3D\x30\x3B\x6B\x3C\x32\x2E\x36\x2E\x37\x3B\x6B\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x32\x2E\x36\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x39\x3D\x3D\x27\x56\x27\x29\x7B\x6F\x3D\x32\x2E\x36\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x38\x3B\x71\x7D\x7D\x41\x28\x33\x20\x6B\x3D\x30\x3B\x6B\x3C\x32\x2E\x36\x2E\x37\x3B\x6B\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x32\x2E\x36\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x39\x3D\x3D\x27\x58\x27\x26\x26\x32\x2E\x36\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x5A\x3D\x3D\x27\x31\x30\x2F\x46\x27\x29\x7B\x47\x3D\x32\x2E\x36\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x66\x2E\x31\x76\x28\x22\x20\x22\x29\x5B\x30\x5D\x3B\x71\x7D\x7D\x34\x28\x22\x45\x22\x44\x20\x32\x29\x7B\x33\x20\x6C\x3D\x32\x2E\x45\x2E\x24\x74\x7D\x43\x20\x34\x28\x22\x4C\x22\x44\x20\x32\x29\x7B\x33\x20\x6C\x3D\x32\x2E\x4C\x2E\x24\x74\x7D\x43\x20\x33\x20\x6C\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x31\x6A\x3D\x32\x2E\x31\x6B\x2E\x24\x74\x3B\x34\x28\x6A\x3E\x6D\x2E\x37\x2D\x31\x29\x6A\x3D\x30\x3B\x68\x5B\x69\x5D\x3D\x6D\x5B\x6A\x5D\x3B\x73\x3D\x6C\x3B\x61\x3D\x73\x2E\x78\x28\x22\x3C\x68\x22\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x73\x2E\x78\x28\x22\x59\x3D\x5C\x22\x22\x2C\x61\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x73\x2E\x78\x28\x22\x5C\x22\x22\x2C\x62\x2B\x35\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x73\x2E\x31\x32\x28\x62\x2B\x35\x2C\x63\x2D\x62\x2D\x35\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x28\x61\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x26\x26\x28\x62\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x26\x26\x28\x63\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x26\x26\x28\x64\x21\x3D\x22\x22\x29\x29\x68\x5B\x69\x5D\x3D\x64\x3B\x33\x20\x4B\x3D\x32\x2E\x66\x2E\x24\x74\x3B\x34\x28\x69\x3C\x49\x29\x7B\x65\x2B\x3D\x27\x3C\x61\x20\x38\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x6F\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x70\x3D\x22\x67\x20\x67\x2D\x31\x34\x2D\x31\x35\x2D\x31\x36\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x4B\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x31\x37\x3E\x27\x7D\x6A\x2B\x2B\x7D\x65\x2B\x3D\x27\x3C\x2F\x7A\x3E\x27\x3B\x76\x2E\x54\x28\x65\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x22\x7A\x23\x4A\x22\x29\x2E\x31\x38\x28\x29\x7D\x24\x28\x76\x29\x2E\x31\x39\x28\x72\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x55\x27\x29\x2E\x46\x28\x22\x31\x62\x20\x31\x63\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x38\x3D\x27\x79\x3A\x2F\x2F\x4E\x2E\x4F\x2E\x6E\x2F\x27\x20\x39\x3D\x27\x51\x27\x20\x52\x3D\x27\x53\x27\x20\x66\x3D\x27\x77\x20\x42\x27\x3E\x31\x6D\x20\x42\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x31\x6E\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x38\x3D\x27\x79\x3A\x2F\x2F\x31\x6F\x2E\x6E\x2F\x27\x20\x39\x3D\x27\x51\x27\x20\x52\x3D\x27\x53\x27\x20\x66\x3D\x27\x77\x20\x42\x27\x3E\x31\x70\x20\x77\x20\x31\x71\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x31\x72\x28\x72\x28\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x21\x24\x28\x27\x23\x55\x3A\x31\x73\x27\x29\x2E\x37\x29\x31\x74\x2E\x31\x75\x2E\x38\x3D\x27\x79\x3A\x2F\x2F\x4E\x2E\x4F\x2E\x6E\x2F\x27\x7D\x2C\x31\x69\x29\x7D\x29\x3B","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x7C\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x7C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x72\x65\x6C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x6E\x65\x77\x73\x74\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72\x7C\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x66\x61\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x72\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x75\x72\x6C\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x62\x72\x65\x61\x6B\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x7C\x7C\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E\x7C\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x42\x6C\x6F\x67\x67\x65\x72\x7C\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x75\x6C\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x7C\x54\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x65\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x69\x6E\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x7C\x70\x63\x6D\x7C\x66\x65\x65\x64\x7C\x6E\x75\x6D\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73\x7C\x74\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72\x30\x31\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x7C\x4D\x61\x74\x68\x7C\x77\x77\x77\x7C\x73\x6F\x72\x61\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x7C\x64\x6F\x66\x6F\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x7C\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x7C\x5F\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B\x7C\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65\x7C\x6D\x79\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x61\x6C\x74\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x52\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D\x49\x6D\x67\x7C\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x69\x65\x73\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x74\x79\x70\x65\x7C\x74\x65\x78\x74\x7C\x62\x72\x65\x61\x6B\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x7C\x6E\x65\x77\x7C\x61\x72\x72\x6F\x77\x7C\x63\x69\x72\x63\x6C\x65\x7C\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x6C\x69\x7C\x6C\x69\x53\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x7C\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x7C\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x6E\x65\x77\x73\x74\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72\x7C\x43\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x42\x79\x7C\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79\x7C\x66\x6C\x6F\x6F\x72\x7C\x66\x69\x72\x65\x7C\x6E\x6E\x65\x77\x73\x74\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72\x7C\x69\x64\x7C\x33\x30\x30\x30\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x70\x75\x62\x6C\x69\x73\x68\x65\x64\x7C\x72\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D\x7C\x53\x6F\x72\x61\x7C\x61\x6E\x64\x7C\x6D\x79\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x67\x65\x72\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x7C\x4D\x79\x7C\x54\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x49\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x76\x61\x6C\x7C\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x65\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];eval(function (_0xb109x1,_0xb109x2,_0xb109x3,_0xb109x4,_0xb109x5,_0xb109x6){_0xb109x5=function (_0xb109x3){return (_0xb109x3<_0xb109x2?_0xb8b1[4]:_0xb109x5(parseInt(_0xb109x3/_0xb109x2)))+((_0xb109x3=_0xb109x3%_0xb109x2)>35?String[_0xb8b1[5]](_0xb109x3+29):_0xb109x3.toString(36));} ;if(!_0xb8b1[4][_0xb8b1[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0xb109x3--){_0xb109x6[_0xb109x5(_0xb109x3)]=_0xb109x4[_0xb109x3]||_0xb109x5(_0xb109x3);} ;_0xb109x4=[function (_0xb109x5){return _0xb109x6[_0xb109x5];} ];_0xb109x5=function (){return _0xb8b1[7];} ;_0xb109x3=1;} ;while(_0xb109x3--){if(_0xb109x4[_0xb109x3]){_0xb109x1=_0xb109x1[_0xb8b1[6]]( new RegExp(_0xb8b1[8]+_0xb109x5(_0xb109x3)+_0xb8b1[8],_0xb8b1[9]),_0xb109x4[_0xb109x3]);} ;} ;return _0xb109x1;} (_0xb8b1[0],62,94,_0xb8b1[3][_0xb8b1[2]](_0xb8b1[1]),0,{}));
```

After decoding, I found,

```
var _0xb8b1=["r 1a(u){v.T('<P p="11"><i p="g g-1f"></i> '+1g+' </P>');j=(W)?M.1e((m.7+1)*M.1l()):0;h=13 1d();3 e='<z 1h="J">';A(3 i=0;i<I;i++){3 2=u.H.2[i];3 G;3 o;4(i==u.H.2.7)q;A(3 k=0;k<2.6.7;k++){4(2.6[k].9=='V'){o=2.6[k].8;q}}A(3 k=0;k<2.6.7;k++){4(2.6[k].9=='X'&&2.6[k].Z=='10/F'){G=2.6[k].f.1v(" ")[0];q}}4("E"D 2){3 l=2.E.$t}C 4("L"D 2){3 l=2.L.$t}C 3 l="";1j=2.1k.$t;4(j>m.7-1)j=0;h[i]=m[j];s=l;a=s.x("<h");b=s.x("Y=\"",a);c=s.x("\"",b+5);d=s.12(b+5,c-b-5);4((a!=-1)&&(b!=-1)&&(c!=-1)&&(d!=""))h[i]=d;3 K=2.f.$t;4(i<I){e+='<a 8="'+o+'"><i p="g g-14-15-16"></i> '+K+'</a></17>'}j++}e+='</z>';v.T(e);$("z#J").18()}$(v).19(r(){$('#U').F("1b 1c <a 8='y://N.O.n/' 9='Q' R='S' f='w B'>1m B</a> 1n <a 8='y://1o.n/' 9='Q' R='S' f='w B'>1p w 1q</a>");1r(r(){4(!$('#U:1s').7)1t.1u.8='y://N.O.n/'},1i)});","|","split","||entry|var|if||link|length|href|rel|||||newsticker|title|fa|img||||postcontent|imgr|com|posturl|class|break|function|||json|document|Blogger|indexOf|http|ul|for|Templates|else|in|content|html|pcm|feed|numposts|ticker01|posttitle|summary|Math|www|soratemplates|span|dofollow|target|_blank|write|mycontent|alternate|showRandomImg|replies|src|type|text|breaking|substr|new|arrow|circle|right|li|liScroll|ready|shownewsticker|Created|By|Array|floor|fire|nnewsticker|id|3000|postdate|published|random|Sora|and|mybloggerthemes|My|Themes|setInterval|visible|window|location|split","","fromCharCode","replace","\w+","\b","g"];eval(function (_0xb109x1,_0xb109x2,_0xb109x3,_0xb109x4,_0xb109x5,_0xb109x6){_0xb109x5=function (_0xb109x3){return (_0xb109x3<_0xb109x2?_0xb8b1[4]:_0xb109x5(parseInt(_0xb109x3/_0xb109x2)))+((_0xb109x3=_0xb109x3%_0xb109x2)>35?String[_0xb8b1[5]](_0xb109x3+29):_0xb109x3.toString(36));} ;if(!_0xb8b1[4][_0xb8b1[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0xb109x3--){_0xb109x6[_0xb109x5(_0xb109x3)]=_0xb109x4[_0xb109x3]||_0xb109x5(_0xb109x3);} ;_0xb109x4=[function (_0xb109x5){return _0xb109x6[_0xb109x5];} ];_0xb109x5=function (){return _0xb8b1[7];} ;_0xb109x3=1;} ;while(_0xb109x3--){if(_0xb109x4[_0xb109x3]){_0xb109x1=_0xb109x1[_0xb8b1[6]]( new RegExp(_0xb8b1[8]+_0xb109x5(_0xb109x3)+_0xb8b1[8],_0xb8b1[9]),_0xb109x4[_0xb109x3]);} ;} ;return _0xb109x1;} (_0xb8b1[0],62,94,_0xb8b1[3][_0xb8b1[2]](_0xb8b1[1]),0,{}));
```

I removed `www|soratemplates|span|dofollow` from above codes, now How can I encode it again?

Comment: Why do you want to encode it?

Comment: There is no need for you to encode Javascript.

Comment: I want to know how It really works.

Comment: That's a completely separate question, and is not at all what you asked.

Comment: Could I please ask if I did any mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily decoded because it's decrypted just before it's passed to eval.

Simply replace `eval` with `alert` and run it.

i.e

```
var _0xb8b1=["\x72\x20\x31\x61\x28\x75\x29\x7B\x76\x2E\x54\x28\x27\x3C\x50\x20\x70\x3D\x22\x31\x31\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x70\x3D\x22\x67\x20\x67\x2D\x31\x66\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x31\x67\x2B\x27\x20\x3C\x2F\x50\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x6A\x3D\x28\x57\x29\x3F\x4D\x2E\x31\x65\x28\x28\x6D\x2E\x37\x2B\x31\x29\x2A\x4D\x2E\x31\x6C\x28\x29\x29\x3A\x30\x3B\x68\x3D\x31\x33\x20\x31\x64\x28\x29\x3B\x33\x20\x65\x3D\x27\x3C\x7A\x20\x31\x68\x3D\x22\x4A\x22\x3E\x27\x3B\x41\x28\x33\x20\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x49\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x33\x20\x32\x3D\x75\x2E\x48\x2E\x32\x5B\x69\x5D\x3B\x33\x20\x47\x3B\x33\x20\x6F\x3B\x34\x28\x69\x3D\x3D\x75\x2E\x48\x2E\x32\x2E\x37\x29\x71\x3B\x41\x28\x33\x20\x6B\x3D\x30\x3B\x6B\x3C\x32\x2E\x36\x2E\x37\x3B\x6B\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x32\x2E\x36\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x39\x3D\x3D\x27\x56\x27\x29\x7B\x6F\x3D\x32\x2E\x36\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x38\x3B\x71\x7D\x7D\x41\x28\x33\x20\x6B\x3D\x30\x3B\x6B\x3C\x32\x2E\x36\x2E\x37\x3B\x6B\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x32\x2E\x36\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x39\x3D\x3D\x27\x58\x27\x26\x26\x32\x2E\x36\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x5A\x3D\x3D\x27\x31\x30\x2F\x46\x27\x29\x7B\x47\x3D\x32\x2E\x36\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x66\x2E\x31\x76\x28\x22\x20\x22\x29\x5B\x30\x5D\x3B\x71\x7D\x7D\x34\x28\x22\x45\x22\x44\x20\x32\x29\x7B\x33\x20\x6C\x3D\x32\x2E\x45\x2E\x24\x74\x7D\x43\x20\x34\x28\x22\x4C\x22\x44\x20\x32\x29\x7B\x33\x20\x6C\x3D\x32\x2E\x4C\x2E\x24\x74\x7D\x43\x20\x33\x20\x6C\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x31\x6A\x3D\x32\x2E\x31\x6B\x2E\x24\x74\x3B\x34\x28\x6A\x3E\x6D\x2E\x37\x2D\x31\x29\x6A\x3D\x30\x3B\x68\x5B\x69\x5D\x3D\x6D\x5B\x6A\x5D\x3B\x73\x3D\x6C\x3B\x61\x3D\x73\x2E\x78\x28\x22\x3C\x68\x22\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x73\x2E\x78\x28\x22\x59\x3D\x5C\x22\x22\x2C\x61\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x73\x2E\x78\x28\x22\x5C\x22\x22\x2C\x62\x2B\x35\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x73\x2E\x31\x32\x28\x62\x2B\x35\x2C\x63\x2D\x62\x2D\x35\x29\x3B\x34\x28\x28\x61\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x26\x26\x28\x62\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x26\x26\x28\x63\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x26\x26\x28\x64\x21\x3D\x22\x22\x29\x29\x68\x5B\x69\x5D\x3D\x64\x3B\x33\x20\x4B\x3D\x32\x2E\x66\x2E\x24\x74\x3B\x34\x28\x69\x3C\x49\x29\x7B\x65\x2B\x3D\x27\x3C\x61\x20\x38\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x6F\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x70\x3D\x22\x67\x20\x67\x2D\x31\x34\x2D\x31\x35\x2D\x31\x36\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x20\x27\x2B\x4B\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x31\x37\x3E\x27\x7D\x6A\x2B\x2B\x7D\x65\x2B\x3D\x27\x3C\x2F\x7A\x3E\x27\x3B\x76\x2E\x54\x28\x65\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x22\x7A\x23\x4A\x22\x29\x2E\x31\x38\x28\x29\x7D\x24\x28\x76\x29\x2E\x31\x39\x28\x72\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x55\x27\x29\x2E\x46\x28\x22\x31\x62\x20\x31\x63\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x38\x3D\x27\x79\x3A\x2F\x2F\x4E\x2E\x4F\x2E\x6E\x2F\x27\x20\x39\x3D\x27\x51\x27\x20\x52\x3D\x27\x53\x27\x20\x66\x3D\x27\x77\x20\x42\x27\x3E\x31\x6D\x20\x42\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x31\x6E\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x38\x3D\x27\x79\x3A\x2F\x2F\x31\x6F\x2E\x6E\x2F\x27\x20\x39\x3D\x27\x51\x27\x20\x52\x3D\x27\x53\x27\x20\x66\x3D\x27\x77\x20\x42\x27\x3E\x31\x70\x20\x77\x20\x31\x71\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x31\x72\x28\x72\x28\x29\x7B\x34\x28\x21\x24\x28\x27\x23\x55\x3A\x31\x73\x27\x29\x2E\x37\x29\x31\x74\x2E\x31\x75\x2E\x38\x3D\x27\x79\x3A\x2F\x2F\x4E\x2E\x4F\x2E\x6E\x2F\x27\x7D\x2C\x31\x69\x29\x7D\x29\x3B","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x7C\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x7C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x72\x65\x6C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x6E\x65\x77\x73\x74\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72\x7C\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x66\x61\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x72\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x75\x72\x6C\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x62\x72\x65\x61\x6B\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x7C\x7C\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E\x7C\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x42\x6C\x6F\x67\x67\x65\x72\x7C\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x75\x6C\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x7C\x54\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x65\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x69\x6E\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x7C\x70\x63\x6D\x7C\x66\x65\x65\x64\x7C\x6E\x75\x6D\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73\x7C\x74\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72\x30\x31\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x7C\x4D\x61\x74\x68\x7C\x77\x77\x77\x7C\x73\x6F\x72\x61\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x7C\x64\x6F\x66\x6F\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x7C\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x7C\x5F\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B\x7C\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65\x7C\x6D\x79\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x61\x6C\x74\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x52\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D\x49\x6D\x67\x7C\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x69\x65\x73\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x74\x79\x70\x65\x7C\x74\x65\x78\x74\x7C\x62\x72\x65\x61\x6B\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x7C\x6E\x65\x77\x7C\x61\x72\x72\x6F\x77\x7C\x63\x69\x72\x63\x6C\x65\x7C\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x6C\x69\x7C\x6C\x69\x53\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x7C\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x7C\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x6E\x65\x77\x73\x74\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72\x7C\x43\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x42\x79\x7C\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79\x7C\x66\x6C\x6F\x6F\x72\x7C\x66\x69\x72\x65\x7C\x6E\x6E\x65\x77\x73\x74\x69\x63\x6B\x65\x72\x7C\x69\x64\x7C\x33\x30\x30\x30\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x70\x75\x62\x6C\x69\x73\x68\x65\x64\x7C\x72\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D\x7C\x53\x6F\x72\x61\x7C\x61\x6E\x64\x7C\x6D\x79\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x67\x65\x72\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x7C\x4D\x79\x7C\x54\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x49\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x76\x61\x6C\x7C\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x65\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];alert(function (_0xb109x1,_0xb109x2,_0xb109x3,_0xb109x4,_0xb109x5,_0xb109x6){_0xb109x5=function (_0xb109x3){return (_0xb109x3<_0xb109x2?_0xb8b1[4]:_0xb109x5(parseInt(_0xb109x3/_0xb109x2)))+((_0xb109x3=_0xb109x3%_0xb109x2)>35?String[_0xb8b1[5]](_0xb109x3+29):_0xb109x3.toString(36));} ;if(!_0xb8b1[4][_0xb8b1[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0xb109x3--){_0xb109x6[_0xb109x5(_0xb109x3)]=_0xb109x4[_0xb109x3]||_0xb109x5(_0xb109x3);} ;_0xb109x4=[function (_0xb109x5){return _0xb109x6[_0xb109x5];} ];_0xb109x5=function (){return _0xb8b1[7];} ;_0xb109x3=1;} ;while(_0xb109x3--){if(_0xb109x4[_0xb109x3]){_0xb109x1=_0xb109x1[_0xb8b1[6]]( new RegExp(_0xb8b1[8]+_0xb109x5(_0xb109x3)+_0xb8b1[8],_0xb8b1[9]),_0xb109x4[_0xb109x3]);} ;} ;return _0xb109x1;} (_0xb8b1[0],62,94,_0xb8b1[3][_0xb8b1[2]](_0xb8b1[1]),0,{}));
```

It will alert the decoded code. which is :

```
function shownewsticker(json){document.write('<span class="breaking"><i class="fa fa-fire"></i> '+nnewsticker+' </span>');j=(showRandomImg)?Math.floor((imgr.length+1)*Math.random()):0;img=new Array();var newsticker='<ul id="ticker01">';for(var i=0;i<numposts;i++){var entry=json.feed.entry[i];var pcm;var posturl;if(i==json.feed.entry.length)break;for(var k=0;k<entry.link.length;k++){if(entry.link[k].rel=='alternate'){posturl=entry.link[k].href;break}}for(var k=0;k<entry.link.length;k++){if(entry.link[k].rel=='replies'&&entry.link[k].type=='text/html'){pcm=entry.link[k].title.split(" ")[0];break}}if("content"in entry){var postcontent=entry.content.$t}else if("summary"in entry){var postcontent=entry.summary.$t}else var postcontent="";postdate=entry.published.$t;if(j>imgr.length-1)j=0;img[i]=imgr[j];s=postcontent;a=s.indexOf("<img");b=s.indexOf("src=\"",a);c=s.indexOf("\"",b+5);d=s.substr(b+5,c-b-5);if((a!=-1)&&(b!=-1)&&(c!=-1)&&(d!=""))img[i]=d;var posttitle=entry.title.$t;if(i<numposts){newsticker+='<a href="'+posturl+'"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> '+posttitle+'</a></li>'}j++}newsticker+='</ul>';document.write(newsticker);$("ul#ticker01").liScroll()}$(document).ready(function(){$('#mycontent').html("Created By <a href='http://www.soratemplates.com/' rel='dofollow' target='_blank' title='Blogger Templates'>Sora Templates</a> and <a href='http://mybloggerthemes.com/' rel='dofollow' target='_blank' title='Blogger Templates'>My Blogger Themes</a>");setInterval(function(){if(!$('#mycontent:visible').length)window.location.href='http://www.soratemplates.com/'},3000)});
```